# Sport activities

Tags: word-choice

Do native speakers use "sport activities"?

"A lot of people aren't as healthy as their parents and grandparents used to be.  People can solve this problem in different ways. There are some ways for solving this problem. People should do sport activities."

Comment: Please split this into two separate questions- one concerning **sport activities** and another about **solve/solving this problem**.

Comment: Done. I removed the second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sport activities" doesn't sound natural. Instead you could use "athletics", or "sports"

Comment: ... or sporting activities.